# Is Hybris installer used for demonstration purposes only?

Tags: installation, sap-commerce-cloud

I've spent a week trying to understand how Hybris installer works and I thought I could create any type of application with recipes. However my teammate said that those recipes  are useless for dev or production setup. But why installer folder is a top folder in Hybris installation? Only for demo?

Answer (score 4):

Your teammate correct, installer used for creating demo system.

Answer (score 1):

In the Hybris WIKI are two sites that explain this one:

[Installing Hybris Using Installer Recipes](https://help.hybris.com/6.4.0/hcd/8c46c266866910149666a0fe4caeee4e.html)

[Installing SAP Hybris Commerce](https://help.hybris.com/6.4.0/hcd/8bf5cfea86691014a00e9705a3c84074.html)

But you can also just have a look into the install recipes. There is no big magic behind it. Just browse to:

```
hybris\installer\recipes\b2c_acc\build.gradle
```

(for example) and have a look into it. First it sets some properties, than it defines which extensions should be used and at last it install addons on other extensions (normally on the storefront).