# What is recipe in SAP Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

When we install recipe it generates only storefront extension, not others what is the reason for that?
Can we create a custom extension using ant modulegen as well?

Answer (score 4):

If you understand the difference between modulegen & Recipes, things will become more clear to you.

### Modulegen

The modulegen tool is delivered with SAP Commerce and can be used to generate sets of dependent extensions to quickly start new projects or create new applications. The modules shipped with SAP Commerce help you to meet client requirements from the very beginning by allowing you to generate fully functional applications that can then be customized. The modulegen tool replaces the schema, package name, extension class prefixes, and some other properties across a set of extensions, all while maintaining the relationships between them. The tool is run as an ant task, so it requires the ant libraries to be present on the system.

Source: [help.hybris](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/f09d46cf4a2546b586ed7021655e4715.html)

### Recipes

To automate your installation of SAP Commerce for development and demonstration purposes, you can use an installer recipe. Recipes are gradle scripts that take care of creating directories, moving files, updating configuration and properties files, and initializing the system.

Source: [help.hybris](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c46c266866910149666a0fe4caeee4e.html)

---

To answer your questions

> When we install recipe it generates only storefront extension, not
>   others what is the reason for that?

Basically, recipe adds a flavor to your project. Let suppose you want to explore the B2C SAP Hybris Commerce, then you just need to install b2c_acc. It will create **localextensions.xml** under your config folder with the all required extensions for B2C. The recipe doesn't generate custom extensions. You have to run the modulegen for that.

> Can we create custom extensions using ant modulegen as well?

Yes, Intended for that purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

[Is Hybris installer used for demonstration purposes only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811263/is-hybris-installer-used-for-demonstration-purposes-only/45938006#45938006)

I think it is about the same issue